XLSX styling in Javascript in HTML does not work
I am trying to create and style an XLSX sheet with javascript in my html file. I can create the XLSX sheet however I cannot style it.
Things I have tried:

I was using <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/xlsx@0.15.1/dist/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>, with this script I can create the sheet but I cannot style it.
Then I tried using <script src="dist/xlsx.bundle.js"></script>, from this link. This also did not work and the error I get with this one is the following: ReferenceError: XLSX is not defined
I have also tried other scripts but they needed me to use "require().." to define the XLSX like this: const XLSX = require('sheetjs-style'') or with require('xlsx') , however it did not work since "require" is not supported in the browser. I also tried the approaches here but still no success.

Here is my code:
<script src="dist/xlsx.bundle.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function createExcel(file_name) {
              var exampleData = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('exampleData').textContent);
              console.log("exampleData: ", exampleData);
              var dataForExcel = [];

              
              for (var field in exampleData) {
                // some data operations that fills the data for excel using
                // dataForExcel.push(....)

                } 

               var worksheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(dataForExcel);

              // Wrap text in cells and adjust row heights for long text
              // Apply text wrapping and center alignment in cells
              dataForExcel.forEach(function(row, rowIndex) {
                var cellValue = row.my_row;
                var cellAddress = XLSX.utils.encode_cell({r: rowIndex, c: 0});
                
                worksheet[cellAddress] = {
                  v: cellValue, 
                  s: { 
                    alignment: { 
                      wrapText: true, // Enable text wrapping
                      horizontal: 'center' // Center text horizontally
                    }
                  }
                };
              });
              }
</script>


you are including the js as a relative url that probably you don't have among your assets.. if you are getting served by the cdn you should use this for example https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/xlsx-js-style if included properly, your code won't blame anymore for XLSX is not defined. Now for everything else, you are missing the statements to create the "book", add the newly created worksheet to it and save everything to file.

By the way I suggest you add in your question some more details, like the exact json string you are supposed to parse and how you are going to transform such data into dataForExcel before passing it to the logic in charge of crafting the excel sheet, I'm sure it would help getting a better answer

@DiegoD the link you suggested fixed the problem. Thanks a lot!
